# Camera Window Size Mismatch in Tkinter Application

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, computer-vision

I'm working on a Tkinter application for live streaming using OpenCV, and I'm facing an issue with the camera window size. The camera resolution is set to 1920x1080, but the displayed window size seems to be inconsistent on different systems.

Problem Description:

```
Scenario 1 (Working): When the display resolution is 1920x1080, the camera window size is correct.
Scenario 2 (Working): With a display resolution of 1366x768, the camera window size is still fine.
Scenario 3 (Issue): However, with a display resolution of 1600x900, the camera window doesn't match the screen width and height. The camera window appears smaller than expected.
```

Here's the relevant part of my code where I set up the camera and canvas:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('')
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()  # to get display resolution
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (screenWidth, screenHeight))
app = LivestreamApp(root, "SID-LITE")

class LivestreamApp:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1920 )
        self.vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
        Width  = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        Height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        print(f"Camera Resolution: {Width} x {Height}")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
```

1. How can I ensure that the camera window size is consistent across different display resolutions? I've tried setting the camera resolution using cv2.VideoCapture.set(), but the issue persists.
2. Are there any additional adjustments or considerations I should be aware of when dealing with different screen resolutions in a Tkinter application with OpenCV?